# Activate "Caps lock" key for different languages

Tags: javascript, flash, keyboard

I want to write a program that can turn on Caps lock key without having the user to press the physical key on his keyboard.

Is there a way to do so in Flash, Javascript - if not, any other languages ?

Comment: Using Python seems to work - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171408/how-to-change-caps-lock-status-without-key-press. But I wonder if I can use Javascript or Flash to do it also.

Comment: This is not possible in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. Can Flash make it?

Comment: I have no idea.  I would assume not, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I've been using Python and the SendKey library for Windows.
http://www.rutherfurd.net/python/sendkeys/

capslock.py

```
import SendKeys
SendKeys.SendKeys("""{CAPSLOCK}""")
```

Answer (score 1):

UGG, THAT WOULD BE ANNOYING.

If you need to display user input in caps you can transform the text when you process the input in the backend, or style it properly when you render the text on the frontend.

Comment: I'm building a device without any input from the user, this "Caps lock" thing is just a hack to turn an external LED on.