# How can I turn on/off Caps Lock, Scroll Lock, Num Lock key programatically on Linux

Tags: c++, keyboard, opensuse, capslock

Is there a simple method to turn on/off Caps Lock, Scroll Lock and Num Lock on Linux (OpenSuse) using C++, what header files need to use? 
I want to control some device simulates keystrokes.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171408/how-to-change-caps-lock-status-without-key-press) question concerns Python, but is essentially the same, since the mechanism is, more or less, language-independent. I don't know if it's POSIX or supported by other Unices at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1

Please go head because this solution just turn on the led of the keyboard, if you need to enable the *caps lock* funcion too, see solution 2.

```
// Linux header, no portable source
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int fd_console = open("/dev/console", O_WRONLY);
  if (fd_console == -1) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening console file descriptor\n";
    exit(-1);
  }
  
  // turn on caps lock
  ioctl(fd_console, 0x4B32, 0x04);

  // turn on num block 
  ioctl(fd_console, 0x4B32, 0x02);
  
  // turn off 
  ioctl(fd_console, 0x4B32, 0x0);
  
  close(fd_console);
  return 0;
}
```

Remember you have to launch your program with superuser privileges in order to write in the file `/dev/console`.

---

## EDIT

## Solution 2

This solution works with X11 window system manager (on linux is almost a standard).

```
// X11 library and testing extensions
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // Get the root display.
  Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  
  // Get the keycode for XK_Caps_Lock keysymbol
  unsigned int keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_Caps_Lock);
  
  // Simulate Press
  XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, True, CurrentTime);
  XFlush(display);
  
  // Simulate Release
  XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, keycode, False, CurrentTime);
  XFlush(display);
 
  return 0;
}
```

*Note: more key-symbol can be found in the [header](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/keysymdef.h)*.

Comment: The super-user privilege thing sounds as silly as Windows often is. The opposite of security, when you have to allow anything in order to do some trivial but crucial little thing. Could it be possible to design a daemon process or something that could do this and provide an API to any non-privileged process?

Comment: Is there an analogue KDSETLED/KDGETLED in windows?

Comment: @MaysSpirit I think should be easier to find a solution for windows. Take a look on google, otherwise open a question on StackOverflow

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Requiring root to Interact with `/dev/console` isn't silly at all. `/dev/tty` is the device node for "whatever terminal session I'm connected to". `/dev/console` is "the system console, regardless of whether I'm the person logged into it". Heck, given `/dev/console` is usually the local VGA/DVI/HDMI/DisplayPort console which only the admin would have physical access to, you *especially* don't want arbitrary users being able to manipulate it because odds are that the admin is the one logged into it. Same reason you don't grant arbitrary people raw access to read `/dev/sdX`.

Comment: In fact, historically, there's been an `/etc/securetty` file that specifies which consoles `root` was allowed to log into directly (i.e. not via `sudo`) and it was common for `/dev/console` to be the only entry.