# Send key combination with python

Tags: python, keyboard, pywin32

I want to be able to send the key combination **SHIFT + CTRL + . (dot)** using the following code:

```
import win32com.client as comclt
wsh= comclt.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
wsh.SendKeys()
```

So far I was able to send  **CTRL + . (dot)** like this :

```
wsh.SendKeys(^.)
```

How do I add the SHIFT key there ?

Thanks to anyone who answers :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Shift use `+`

Complete list is available here: [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

... To specify that a combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held down while several other keys are pressed, create a compound string argument with the modified keystrokes enclosed in parentheses. For example, to send the keystroke combination that specifies that the SHIFT key is held down while:

- e and c are pressed, send the string argument "+(ec)".
- e is pressed, followed by a lone c (with no SHIFT), send the string argument "+ec". ...